# Combining multiple rows values in one column, based on frequency of another value in R

Tags: r, subset, tidyverse, frequency

I want to subset a large dataset based on the frequency of variables in column A. The variables in Column B will disappear, because i don't use them in the subset. I want to keep these however, to add some additional information about the frequency of a variable in column A.

Data example

```
A   B
A1  2001 
A1  2005
A1  2010
B2  2001
B3  2005
B3  2010
```

The result want:

```
A  Freq  B
A1  3    2001, 2005, 2010
B2  1    2001
B3  2    2005, 2010
```

I use the `table` function to make frequency table, but i cant figure out how to add the column with years seperated by some seperator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `dplyr` for this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A= c("A1", "A1", "B2", "B3", "B3"),
  B = c(2001,2005,2010,2001,2005)
)

library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(count = n(), year = paste(B, collapse = ","))
```